# MPMoviePlayerController not in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to add a MPMoviePlayerController to a UIView.

I am doing it, but it is appearing at the top of my view instead of the position the UIView has in my storyboard.

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.view.frame = videoView.bounds;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is videoView?  What is self.view?  You set it to videoView.bounds, so the x,y origins are at o,o.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];` to `[videoView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];`

If you want your moviePlayer to be at the position of your UIView, you have to add it as a subview to that particular UIView. If you add your moviePlayer to `self.view` it will be added on top of every other subview.

EDIT: If you want to add the moviePlayer as a subview to your main view, then change `moviePlayer.view.frame = videoView.bounds;` to `moviePlayer.view.frame = videoView.frame;`